# 'EmployeeContext' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.ts(2702)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

```
<EmployeeContext.Provider> 
value={addEmployee, DefaultData, sortedEmployees, deleteEmployee, updateEmployee}
  {props.children};
</EmployeeContext.Provider>
```

here Im having problem as stated in title. please anyone help

Comment: It'd be helpful if you provided the definition of `EmployeeContext`, it's difficult to tell what could be wrong now.

Answer (score 3):

This post is a bit old but still I will comment here

Seems like you are using a .ts extension for the context file, change it to .tsx

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are using the EmployeeContext defined as type and not the one returned by `createContext()` like this:

```
const EmployeeContext = React.createContext(null);
```